# How to calculate proxy latency when sending an HTTP request?

Tags: http, go, networking, network-programming

As you all know we can easily get duration details of an HTTP request by using [ClientTrace](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptrace#ClientTrace). Like DNS time, TTFB, etc. But what if I use a proxy server while sending the request? As far as I know, ClientTrace does not have a hook for calculating the proxy server latency. Is there any other way to eliminate proxy server latency from the total request duration?

What I want to achieve;

Life cycle without proxy;

```
Client --- request_duration --->  Server
Client <-- response_duration ---  Server
```

Life cycle with a proxy;

```
Client --- request_proxy_latency  ---> Proxy --- request_duration --->  Server
Client <-- response_proxy_latency ---- Proxy <-- response_duration ---  Server
```

In both cases above I want to calculate only `request_duration + response_duration`.